# Why md-datepicker NOT opens in current date?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

Hi I use angular material date picker.
The small issue is that when I click on date and open calendar - it opens and shows not today date .but some far far date.
How to make calendar open on today date or at least on ng-model date?

shows date:

[image]

opens calendar when clicked:

[image]

here is html:

```
  <md-datepicker class="font" ng-model="vm.startDate"></md-datepicker>
```

js to get model:

```
     vm.startDate = new Date();
```

thanks for help in advance.

UPDATE:
Have noticed strange behavior:

CASE1:
when I scroll page and calendar is almost on top of page:

[image]

and when I open calendar it shows current date like this:

[image]

CASE2:
same but when datepicker scrolled on bottom page:
the current date if far far behind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.startDate = new Date();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <md-content>
      <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.startDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when my date picker was on bottom of page having scrollbar and angular material version was 1.1.1

This can be fixed easily if angular material js is upgraded to latest version.

If you are hessitant of upgrading your angular material version

try something like this in controller

```
$scope.datepickeropen = function(){
    $timeout(function () {
        var e1 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e1.which = 40; // it is down
        $(".md-datepicker-calendar .md-focus").trigger(e1);
        var e2 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e2.which = 38; // it is up
        $(".md-datepicker-calendar .md-focus").trigger(e2);
    },500)
}
```

HTML as

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Withdrawal Date</label>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="date" ng-focus="datepickeropen()"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();
  $scope.datepickeropen = function(){
      $timeout(function () {
          var e1 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
          e1.which = 40; // it is down
          $(".md-datepicker-calendar .md-focus").trigger(e1);
          var e2 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
          e2.which = 38; // it is up
          $(".md-datepicker-calendar .md-focus").trigger(e2);
      },500)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style="padding: 40px;"  class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>
<div>Dummy Text for scroll on page</div>

<h4>Standard date-picker <u>with issue fixed</u></h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-hide-icons="triangle" ng-focus="datepickeropen()"></md-datepicker>
    
    <h4>Standard date-picker <u>with issue</u></h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-hide-icons="triangle"></md-datepicker>
    

</div>
```